# Проверить есть ли запись в MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить есть ли конкретное значение в базе данных MySQL? Нужно реализовать метод на C# с проверкой. Например, есть таблица users:

```
|-----------Users----------|
|-id-|--user--|--password--|
|-01-|--Вася--|--********--|
|-02-|--Петя--|--********--|
|-03-|--Коля--|--********--|
```

Если в таблице есть пользователь с именем "Петя" - выводим: "Такой пользователь уже есть", и наоборот. Всем большое спасибо за ответы.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE user='Вася'`

Comment: Это самые основы SQL, описываемые в любом учебнике по нему, почему у вас вдруг возникли проблемы с этим?

Comment: Да запрос то я знаю) Мне нужен метод на C#, который возвращает true если запись есть в базе, и false если нет.

Comment: «c sharp mysql» тоже неплохо гуглится, в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Проблема в правильной реализации метода, я написал выше. Те, что в гугле, отрабатывают не корректно. Вы минусов понаставили, а ничего конкретного не предложили. Не по людски как то

Comment: Так мы же предложим всё то же самое, что есть в гугле :) Вот если бы вы во всех подробностях написали, что там у вас некорректно отрабатывает, тогда был бы дельный разговор

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так не делал , но видимо вы хотите что-то вроде:

```
private bool _checkUser(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE user='Вася';";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
             return true;
            }else return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Пример с MySql.Data

```
private bool _checkUser(string UserName){
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn = new 
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Persist Security 
    Info=False;server=localhost;database=dbname;uid=root;password=" + dbpassword);
    MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE user=@name";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",UserName);
    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();                
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        this.Close();
    }  
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
  if(reader.Read())return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! А как бы вы сделали? Ведь в том то и смысл чтобы сделать правильно)

Comment: А какую вы технологию используете для организации работы с бд ?

Comment: using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Comment: Если в таблице может быть много пользователей Вася, то эффективнее делать что-то вроде `SELECT TOP 1 UserID FORM Users WHERE user=@name` и проверять на null - тогда sql просто не-null на первом же найденном пользователе, а не будет перебирать всех пользователей ради подсчета Вась

Comment: Исходя из задачи я подумал что user - Primary Key .